# Set proof (symmetric difference of disjoint set)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

The question:

Prove this is true: ($A$ $\setminus$ $B$) $\cup $ ($B$ $\setminus$ $A$) = ($A$ $\cup$ $B$) iff ($A$ $\cap$ $B$) = $ \emptyset$

```
My idea was to prove this by contrapositive, but I got stuck. Here's what I have:
```

Assume ($A$ $\cap$ $B$) $\neq $ $ \emptyset$.

Take $x$ to be an element of ($A$ $\cap$ $B$).

Then $x$ $\in$ $A$ and $x$ $\in$ $B$.

```
This is where I got stuck.
```

Somehow, I must prove that $x$ $\in$ ($A$ $\setminus$ $B$) $\cup $ ($B$ $\setminus$ $A$). If someone could tell me how to conclude that step, I know how to prove that ($A$ $\setminus$ $B$) $\cup $ ($B$ $\setminus$ $A$) $\neq$ ($A$ $\cup$ $B$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prove this you have to prove both direction.

From where you are you are proving $\Rightarrow$ to finish that proof just use what's below.
Since it is a member of both $A$ and $B$ then it can't be a member of $A\setminus B$ or $B \setminus A$ so it can't be in the union. That proves one direction.

To prove $\Leftarrow$ assume that The intersection is $\varnothing$ then if you have an element of $A$ is must not be a member of $B$ so $A\setminus B=A$. The same proof works with $B$ so it must equal $A\cup B$

Comment: Thank you! I have a clearer understanding of the problem now.